# A few generic views under one URL

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm facing a issue with setting up a few generic views on this same certain URL. I would like to have a modeled my API as below:

GET /cars/ <- car list

POST /cars/ <- add new car

GET /cars/uuid/ <- get particular car

PUT /cars/uuid/ <- edit particular car

DELETE /cars/uuid/ <- delete specific car

So finally my issue is that the first include in urlconfig is able to perform the HTTP method, on rest of them I'm always getting "Method Not Allowed:". In above example it's occurs for PUT and DELETE. Is it possible to resolve URL as above or should I add prefixes like /cars/get/uuid?

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CarListApi.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('', CarCreateApi.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('<uuid:uuid>/', CarDeleteApi.as_view(), name='delete'),
    path('<uuid:uuid>/', CarUpdateApi.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('<uuid:uuid>/', CarDetailApi.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

**partial views.py**

```
class CarUpdateApi(generics.UpdateAPIView,
                   generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
    http_method_names = ['delete', 'get', 'post', 'put']

    @extend_schema_serializer(component_name="CarUpdateInputSerializer")
    class InputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Car
            fields = ['plate', 'make', 'model', 'uuid']

    @extend_schema(request=InputSerializer, responses={201: InputSerializer})
    def put(self, request, uuid):
        serializer = self.InputSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            car = car_update(serializer.validated_data, uuid)
            return Response(self.InputSerializer(car).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class CarDeleteApi(generics.DestroyAPIView,
                   generics.GenericAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['delete', 'get', 'post', 'put']

    @extend_schema_serializer(component_name='CarDeleteInputSerializer')
    class InputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Car
            fields = ['uuid']

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.InputSerializer

    def delete(self, request, uuid, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.InputSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) and car_delete(uuid):
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The url pattern has to have only the urls, and in the views you separated the business logic for the http methods. On urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CarApi.as_view(), name='car'),
    path('<uuid:uuid>/', SpecificApi.as_view(), name='specific'),
]
```

and then in the views, something like:

```
class CarApi(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        # logic for get and return car list
    def post(self, request):
        # logic for add card
```

Comment: I am trying to follow this style guide so basically each endpoint should has own URL, own serializer and view https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-Styleguide#urls

Comment: That's the problem. If you want to use that style, you need to use one url for each view and serializer, so change the urls.py to use another url for create and update.
If you use 1 url and 3 http methods is another style.